# onBackPressed does work on fragments using navigation in kotlin

Tags: android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation, onbackpressed

i am implementing an android applicationg opening the camera to record video . I am using navigation to go towards the camera fragment but i can go back to the previous fragment when BackPressing . I receive the warning :

> Cancelling event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_BACK, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x68, repeatCount=0, eventTime=224793910, downTime=224793513, deviceId=-1, source=0x101, displayId=0 }